# Prove that we cannot found any simple algebraic sloution for $n>2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

for this sequance we can write this formula:$\{1-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,...\}=(-1)^n$

for this also we can do that: $\{-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,...\}=(-1)^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

But how to prone there is no simple algebraic formula for $n>2$ (by simple algebric I mean it doesn't use trigonometry or absoluting value or floor function). I mean that we have only the permission to use four main calculations and power and radicals.

Comment: Cycles of 2^n should be feasible.

Comment: how do you say this?

Comment: ${n \choose 4}$ has a 4 odds, 4 evens pattern; ${n \choose 8}$ has a 8 odds, 8 evens pattern, etc.

Comment: $(-1)^n = 0$ for some $n$ ? is this possible ?

Comment: @ ritwik sinha n is a natural number then the possible slouyions are $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @TahaAkbari see the sequence , your first term is $1 + -1 = 0$ and that is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2-odds, 2-evens pattern is related to ${n \choose 2}$

${n \choose 4}$ has a 4 odds, 4 evens pattern; ${n \choose 8}$ has a 8 odds, 8 evens pattern, etc. So these numbers can be fed into the exponent of $-1$ to produce alternative sign patterns $2^n$ of each sign.

I suspect that other numbers are not feasible under the rules you suggest, but I also think a proof would be tough.

Comment: I suspect the proof is not so hard if one excludes radicals - once one establishes that ${n \choose k}$ has a period of $2^m$ mod $2$ for some $m$, one gets that all integer valued polynomials have a period of $2^m$ mod $2$. If you can then establish that all feasible expressions are $(-1)^{f(n)}$, you're basically done. (Radicals introduce a whole can of worms. If one lets in complex numbers, alternations of length $3$ are easy. I suspect it can be done with the real numbers too - and proofs or examples could require some serious tools)